# link rel='preload' is giving a 404 error, but the file is there

Tags: wordpress, relative-path

For preloading a font for my website, the console shows the error below:

> net::ERR_ABORTED 404

The font file is situated at the exact path that is specified.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```
<link rel='preload' href="/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/fonts/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
```

Comment: does it display 404 error when you just open the link to the font via view source or something?

Comment: When I paste the full link in the address bar it also shows a 404, yes.

Comment: if the absolute path doesn't work. you need to get that sorted our first

Comment: Thanks for your replies Joe! How would you handle this? I mean, the file is there... could it be the file is corrupted or something like that?

Comment: You haven't answered the fairly important question, though: what happens when _you_ try to load that URL yourself, by pasting it (not typing! copy-paste it. This is very important) onto your domain in the URL bar and hitting enter? Does it spawn a download? Does nothing happen? If the latter, what do your dev tools say? Specifically, is there an error in the console tab, and what is the network response that you can see in the network tab?

Comment: Thank you for your reply and patience. I'm very inexperienced when it comes to this. I tried the method you suggested earlier today in my office. I copy-pasted the URL after our .nl/ domain, and it showed a 404. When I just did the same thing from my home pc, it prompted the download message. So I checked the console to see if the error was there, and it still is. I whip out my work-laptop at home just now, and there THE ERROR IS GONE. I'm lost.